# Is secretAccessKey necessary in awsmobile configure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

Is secretAccessKey necessary?
Thanks.

(1) Analytics

```
$npm i -g awsmobile-cli
$awsmobile configure
```

Here, we don't need to input secretAccessKey.

[image]

(2) IAM

```
$awsmobile configure
```

However,  we need to input secretAccessKey here.

[image]

Comment: I use the same command, sometimes I should input secretAccessKey, sometimes not. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You **must input secretAccessKey** for the cli to be able to run.

Please be notice that **accesskeyID is like your username** and **secretAccessKey is like your password**.

Do not post your real secretAccessKey here, otherwise your AWS account is in jeopardy.